# Building an MVC3 route that has two different parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

Here's what I want the user to see when visiting the page:

```
www.mywebsite.com/verify/sergiotapia/ASD98H1D9H12D081HD
```

Where `sergiotapia` is a username from my database, and `OUAHSDFUOHASDFOUAHSDF` is a generated field within User table.

This is for email verification purposes.

How would the route for this type of URL be, and also how would the ActionMethod signature be?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Verify",
    "verify/{username}/{token}",
    new { controller = "Verify", action = "Index" }
);
```

and the controller:

```
public class VerifyController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string username, string token)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that simple? :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SergioTapia, why should it be hard?